# Complain about Debugging

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer

I am using a VisualStudio for developing and debugging my html. But, when i debug my html file after few changes in it, my browser showing the result page which is previous. Each and every time i am hitting refresh few times to get my exact result.

Is there anyway to achieve the resultant page with my last changes without hitting refresh?

Comment: Have you checked that in your web browser it's set to check for new versions of the page every time? In IE, the option would be Tools > Internet Options > Settings (in the browsing history section) > Then you have options for 'Check for new versions of stored pages' etc

Comment: Wait, so, you want to refresh the page...without refreshing? You _do_ realize that http (the common protocol for html content) is _stateless_ and doesn't hold a connection to the server, and hence _can't_ know that the server's data changes without asking the server explicitly, right?

Comment: As @dougajmcdonald said, but you must also clear the browser's cache to be sure you will get the page you want. In Firefox: Tools->Clear Recent History . Similar for others, though perhaps "Clear Cache" for others.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys, There is no link to the any of the servers. I am just debugging my html file in localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to force a full refresh and ignore any cached copies of the page.

This saves you having to clear your entire cache out completely all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Press `CTRL-SHIFT-DEL` and select "cache" only. This will ensure your previous page in no longer in memory. Then refresh.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Each and every time deleting the catch and refreshing is not good at and all only know. I am searching for a better way.

Comment: You can completely disable the cache in your browser settings.

Comment: Could you explain how to disable the cache in IE?

Comment: I'm not going through ALL versions of IE, sorry.